# postgres timestamptz timezone wierdness

Tags: postgresql

I'm developing my first postgres database schema and I'm running into a little strangeness with the timezones on the timestamptz data type.

After I create the table and use the `now()` function to input data into the column, I get `2015-11-17 12:10:05.764088-08` as the result. I don't understand what the "764088-08" means for a time zone marker. The postgres documentation says it should look something like this:

`'2004-10-19 10:23:54+02'`

I understand the second timezone format, but the first one is a big mystery to me. Am I simply missing something? Is the `now()` function not what you want to use?

Comment: These 764088 are microseconds. The timestamp is shown In UTC-08:00 timezone.

Comment: The timestamp is in the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The part `05.764088` refers to the current **seconds**. It just gives finer precision and returns the exact microseconds(in this case `764088`) as well. The `-08` in the end refers to the **timezone**:

> The time zone offset from UTC, measured in seconds. Positive values
>   correspond to time zones east of UTC, negative values to zones west of
>   UTC. (Technically, PostgreSQL uses UT1 because leap seconds are not
>   handled.)

The function `now()` is the traditional PostgreSQL equivalent to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. You can see exact details [in the official documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT).